# Very big event about import eclipse for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

i have a big project and after close and open eclipse
i could not seen it and i import it again
and when import finished
size of all file become 0 byte
all my project losed
I dont shut down my system and ctrl+z dont work.
please give me a way to restore it

EDITE
when i go to my project my image are visible and i can see it picture but when i click it
system give me a message that file is emptry

Comment: are you targeting the right workspace?

Comment: @  TheWizKid95 ok i import it from workspace

Comment: I suppose this is a pointless question, but you do back up your source code don't you?  Or do you use SVN, GIT or other VCS?  I don't know Eclipse, but in my IDE (IDEA) there is a local history from which you can recover files.

Comment: @ Simon No i dont use any thing(for ex:Git) that i can restore it .

Comment: please Help me my project was very big.and ....

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm - and please, I feel like a school master, use version control and backup!

Answer (score 0):

Go to where your workspace is on your computer. If you can't find it look in the actual eclipse or sdk folder itself for your files. If that doesn't work do a general search on your computer for any file you previously saved.

Comment: @ Can i restore it by a program backUp? No i dont have save it before.

Comment: @ SmulianJulian seven -windows

Comment: If your files are there but your data in the file is gone then I  don't know What to tell you.

Comment: Do you know how to search the entire computer for files?